# Terraform: Using aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule with a list of cidr_ipv4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm currently working with **Terraform to manage AWS Security Group rules.** I recently switched from using the older `aws_security_group_rule` to the recommended `aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule` for my ingress rules based on the [following note from Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule):

> NOTE on Security Groups and Security Group Rules: Terraform currently provides a Security Group resource with ingress and egress rules defined in-line and a Security Group Rule resource which manages one or more ingress or egress rules. Both of these resources were added before AWS assigned a security group rule unique ID, and they do not work well in all scenarios using the description and tags attributes, which rely on the unique ID. The `aws_vpc_security_group_egress_rule` and `aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule` resources have been added to address these limitations and should be used for all new security group rules. You should not use the `aws_vpc_security_group_egress_rule` and `aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule` resources in conjunction with an `aws_security_group` resource with in-line rules or with `aws_security_group_rule` resources defined for the same Security Group, as rule conflicts may occur and rules will be overwritten.

However, when I attempted to use a list of CIDR blocks for the `cidr_ipv4` argument of the `aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule`, I encountered the following error:

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on ../modules/my_ec2/ec2.tf line 84, in resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "example":
│   84:   cidr_ipv4         = var.ingress_cidr_blocks
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.ingress_cidr_blocks is a list of dynamic
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_ipv4": string required.
```

It seems that the `aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule` expects a single string for `cidr_ipv4`, unlike the older `aws_security_group_rule` which accepted a list.

To address this, my immediate thought is to perhaps create a separate resource for each CIDR block, potentially using the `count` attribute.

Is this the recommended approach or are there other more efficient solutions to this problem?

For reference, I tried to use the `count` attribute within the resource `aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule`.

```
resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "example" {
  count = length(var.ingress_cidr_blocks)

  # ... other parameters ...

  cidr_ipv4         = var.ingress_cidr_blocks[count.index]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.this.id
}
```

```
variable "ingress_cidr_blocks" {
  description = "List of CIDR blocks for ingress traffic"
  type = list(object({
    cidr_ipv4   = string
    from_port   = number
    to_port     = number
    ip_protocol = string
    description = string
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `ingress_cidr_blocks` variable definition and the value you are assigning to it?

Comment: In most scenarios, I'd also use for_each over count & if you only have a couple of ingress rules, a separate block for each rule with the same security_group_id defined in each one would work too. As Marko mentioned, please add the ingress_cidr_blocks variable definition.

Comment: Thank you @MarkoE and @paulg. I have added the `ingress_cidr_blocks` variable definition for your reference. I now used the approach `count` I  mentioned and it's all good. I think it's clear that way.